# Firing keyboard events not working as expected in Jest / jsdom / React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, keyboard-events, jsdom

I've mocked together a little example - Click Button 1, and 2 more buttons display.

I can test this journey through clicks perfectly fine - However, when I try to test Enter key presses on my button, nothing seems to happen, even though things are logging in the console as expected with the event listeners I've placed in the test.

I've created a sandbox with the code here:
[https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-beaver-uetbm?file=/src/**tests**/app.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-beaver-uetbm?file=/src/__tests__/app.js)

```
it('should display additional buttons when "Button 1" has been pressed via keyboard', () => {
    const {button1, button2} = renderApp()

    button1.addEventListener('keydown', () =>
      console.log('Button 1 has been pressed - keydown'),
    )

    fireEvent.keyDown(button1, {
      key: 'Enter',
      code: 13,
      charCode: 13,
      keyCode: 13,
    })

    expect(button2).toBeVisible()
});
```

I can force this to work in my component by adding an `onKeyPress` prop, but that feels like duplicating code for the sake of making a test pass - And I don't like the idea of that when it works as standard in the browser anyway?

```
<button
        onClick={() => setShowButtons(!showButtons)}
        // this works, but I don't think I should be duplicating code to appease tests?
        // onKeyDown={e => e.keyCode === 13 && setShowButtons(!showButtons)}
      >
        Button 1
</button>
```

It seems the fired events are explicitly looking for the events they're tied to, and not byproducts - Such as pressing enter on a button and expecting a click event to fire.  Regardless of this being standard browser behaviour?  Maybe I'm wrong?

I am well and truly stumped - I feel like this SHOULD work?  Any help would be great!  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need wrap your `expect` in a `waitFor(() => expect(button2).toBeVisible())`

Comment: That's frustratingly worked in this example!  I did however have the waitFor in my actual code and it still failed - So I'm thinking there's something else up now!  Back to the drawing board!  Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: It could also be that you're rendering your component, querying and caching the button elements and then asserting on these. It may be worth querying `button2` *after* you've performed the `keydown` event. See https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro#full-example. Also, a more idiomatic way to query these would be `screen.getByRole('button', { name: /button 2/i })`, this ensures you're checking using the accessible button role rather than just any text on the page.